# use readLines() in R without waiting for an ENTER

Tags: r

I am working on a small Rscript that has a `readLines` function:

```
n <- readLines("stdin",n=1);
      if (n =="y"){ ... }
```

I want to know if there is a way for R to go to the next part of the script without waiting for me to hit the ENTER button after I gave the input. In my script I only care whether I type in "n" or not.

Comment: You may use [`scan`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scan.html) for this.

Comment: Could you show me an example? Just changing it for the readLines function?

Comment: It works for me as `scan(n=1)` and it will return the empty list (on Enter) or a letter.

Comment: It is not working for me. I used `n <- scan("stdin",n=1)` but it still waiting for an ENTER after I type in something. Plus I got an error.

Comment: For Linux-Mac there a [`keypress`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/keypress/html/keypress.html) library, which you can try.

Comment: Great! That solved my problem! Cheers!